# Set axis for spin from custom orientation

Tags: python

I want create custom operator, which will replace bpy.ops.mesh.spin()
Instead of taking rotation axis from view, i want to take it from custom axis orientation.

[image: Custom axis UI]

I know how to get matrix for it:

```
m = bpy.context.scene.orientations[0].matrix
```

but need to know how to get this axis information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From m = bpy.context.scene.orientations[0].matrix

Transformed X, Y and Z axis (in world coordinates) are:

```
x = m * Vector( (1, 0, 0) )
Y = m * Vector( (0, 1, 0) )
z = m * Vector( (0, 0, 1) )
```

If you need it in an object local coordinates:

```
x_local = obj.matrix_world.inverted() * x
y_local = obj.matrix_world.inverted() * y
z_local = obj.matrix_world.inverted() * z
```

Comment: Thank you, lemon. So i need z=m*Vector((0, 0, 1)) as axis for bpy.ops.mesh.spin(axis=z)